# Magento2 How to Pass Parameter as Object in GraphQL?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, graphql, magento2.4.4

I want to send parameter as object in Graphql but Internal server error occurs. For Reference i have attached graph query and error generated screenshot.
I have also attached model and schema.graphql file's data and path.

Graphql Query and Error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdgZd.png

> Vendor\Module\etc\schema.graphqls

```
    type Query {
        Getproductbyid(input: Getbyidinput!): Getbyidoutput @resolver(class: "\\Vendor\\Module_name\\Model\\Resolver\\setproductwebp") @doc(description:"Contact us form") 
    }

@doc (description:"Get Product Value By Sku.......")
input Getbyidinput {
    sku : String
    base64_encoded_data : String
    type : String
    name : String
}

type Getbyidoutput {
 message :String
}
```

> Vendor\Module\Model\Resolver\Setproductwebp.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlNoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\GalleryManagement;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Api\ImageContentValidatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;


class Setproductwebp implements ResolverInterface
{

    private  $helperapi;
    private  $helpercustomer;
    private  $filter;

    public function __construct(

        GalleryManagement $gallery,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterface $entry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        Data $helper,
        ImageContentValidatorInterface $contentValidator,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\Data\ImageContentInterface $imageContentInterface
    ) {
        $this->gallery = $gallery;
        $this->entry=$entry;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->imageContentInterface=$imageContentInterface;
        $this->contentValidator = $contentValidator;
    }


    public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
    {
        try {
            $sku = $args['input']['sku'];
            $base64_encoded_data=$args['input']['base64_encoded_data'];
            $type=$args['input']['type'];
            $name=$args['input']['name'];
            $entry = array("content" => array("base64_encoded_data"=> $base64_encoded_data, "type"=> $type, "name"=> $name));

             $storeManager->info(print_r($entry,true));
             $result = $this->gallery->create($sku,$entry);
             $output = ['message' => 'Webp Image uploaded' ];


        }
        catch (\Exception $exception)
        {
            $output['message'] = "not work";
            return $output;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I checked below the line in your code is causing the issue

```
$result = $this->gallery->create($sku,$entry);
```

Here you are trying to create a product gallery image programmatically. Here

> Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\GalleryManagement::create()

the function expects argument two to be the type of

> Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterface

but you are passing an array to it, which is causing a type error issue.

Please check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/249132/84221) link for reference to programmatically create a product image. Thanks! :)